# Small form factor over voltage protection circuit for 5V power supply

Tags: power-supply

[image]

I would like to add small form factor OVP (Over voltage protection) circuit after my power JACK. Could you please any one help me on this, because we have similar kind of 2 adapters one is 5V and another one is 12V. So by mistaken we will connect and power-up 5Volt circuit through 12 Volt adapter. So i need to add OVP circuit.

[image]

please guide me: my idea about series resistor with 5.1V zener diode, Voltage break down is 5.1V and power peak pulse max 75Watts it will accept max 5A current

shall i implement this?

Comment: Does D2 not serve this purpose?

Comment: @Botnic No! TVSes aren't designed for sustained overvoltage.

Comment: @NickJohnson that's why the fuse is, i.e to make it temporarly, those to protect the connected sensitive device.

Comment: Hi all, Shall i add zener diode series with resistor in the circuit between D2 and R797?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a P-channel MOSFET as a series switch, with its gate pulled to ground by a comparator.  Bypass the comparator's positive supply pin with a 0.1uF capacitor to ground.  Provide a reference for the comparator's non-inverting input with a 5.6V Zener diode and current limiting resistor.  Sample the DC supply at the comaparator's inverting input.  The comparator will switch the MOSFET off when the input rises above ~5.6V.

This schematic is an example using half of an LM393N comparator (1), a 1N5232B Zener diode and an IRFU5305 P-channel MOSFET.  The power and comparator elements of the LM393N are split into three sections in this schematic; just pay attention to the pin numbers as they relate to the 8-DIP package.

The MOSFET won't dissipate more than 260mW at 2A, so you shouldn't need a heatsink if the ambient temperature is reasonable.

If you use different components, ensure that your MOSFET's gate-source voltage (Vgs) is well above 12V, and that your comparator can operate with a supply from 5V to above 12V.  There are lots of options in both through-hole and surface mount components.

MOSFET power dissipation in watts (W) equals current (I) squared times MOSFET on-resistance (Rdson): W = I x I x Rdson.  Use the maximum Rdson value in the datasheet.

MOSFET junction temperature rise (Tr) without a heatsink equals power dissipation (W) times junction-to-ambient thermal resistance (RΦja): Tr = W x RΦja.

MOSFET junction temperature (Tj) equals ambient temperature (Ta) plus junction temperature rise (Tr): Tj = Ta + Tr.  Keep junction temperature well below the datasheet maximum.

[image: OVP Circuit Example]

Comment: hi Eric thanks for your answer, but if i couldn't implement this because cost effective and space accommodation is high.

Comment: Are you adding this feature to an existing circuit, or as part of a new project? Will you make a circuit board? Do you want to use through-hole or surface-mount parts? / The circuit I suggested would cost $2.45 at Digi-Key prices, and it consists of only six parts. That's pretty cheap and small. Unless you use surface-mount parts, you won't get it much smaller. / There are two smaller solutions that I can think of: 1) a parallel crowbar, which was already rejected, or 2) a specialized OVP controller IC like the Linear Technologies [LTC4365](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/4365fa.pdf).

Comment: Here's the smallest possible solution. The ON Semiconductor [NCP392A](http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/NCP392A-D.PDF) is a 1.3mm x 2.0mm BGA part that requires only one 0.1uF external capacitor to provide OVP at 5.9V, with 4.5A of current capability.  $1.15 each at Mouser.

Comment: i really appreciate your help thanks. i am doing re-spin activity for existing board.so our 1st revision we had faced some issues, it will updated and going to release, so my idea is to added new zener diode circuitry.

Comment: Hello past, future here :) What components would be needed to retrofit this design to protect from ebike voltages, which can go up to 40/50V is range?

Answer (score 4):

You could add a 5V LDO regulator to the 5V circuit. Something like the [LD2981](http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/datasheet/CD00001635.pdf), *however* it will probably appear to work and go into overtemperature protection if a 12V adapter is plugged in and there is substantial current flowing.

Perhaps your circuit could detect the application of overvoltage and put itself into a low current state for the duration of the overvoltage. Something like a voltage divider and ADC or comparator. That will also indicate to the user that they made a mistake and should change adapters.

The LDO will prevent even a momentary application of overvoltage, and your circuit has a bit of time to react before the LDO heats up too much.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion.But it will not suitable for my application because my load current should be 2Amps, and mentioned LDO will give 100mAmps output. so my aim is need to protect my regulator circuitry from Over voltage protection. and "main thing is COST EFFECTIVE"

Comment: You can use a bigger regulator then. Don't forget the second word in 'cost effective'. The primary thing is to design something that protects effectively, otherwise it's entirely a waste of money.

Answer (score 2):

Your easiest option is probably a [crowbar circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crowbar_(circuit)). This is designed such that when the voltage crosses a threshold level, it shorts the input to ground, which will cause the fuse to blow.

Comment: sorry i couldn't use you suggestion.because my fuse is an "Etch" type.

Comment: @ramesh6663 What in the world is your reason to add a PCB-trace fuse? That's just going to be shooting you in the foot over and over and over and over. As in this case as well. You cannot build a parallel OVP and then complain about your trace fuse blowing, that's not how current and voltage work.

Comment: Using a trace as a fuse is a terrible idea, as @Asmyldof points out. It won't be well controlled in trip current, either. If you must, you can get SMT fuses, which would at least be consistent and replaceable.